# The rate of people reaching the age of 65 and over in Japan is X%

Tags: phrase-usage

1. **The rate of** people reaching the age of 65 and over in Japan is X%.
2. **The rate of** the 65-and-over age group in Japan is X%.

I know "the proportion of" works in both cases, but I'm not sure if "the rate of" does. And what if I rephrase the first sentence into the second one, does the answer change?

Comment: Try "The percentage of . . ."

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "reaching". 35% of the people die before reaching age 65? 1 in 3 people die earlier? Or that currently 65% of the population are age 65 or older?

Comment: Yes, I do know "the percentage of..." works, but I'm trying to use "the rate of" correctly. 

@TimRonsomedevice Yeah I think we should only discuss the second sentence.

Comment: [X percentage] of Japanese people reach the age of 65 and over. One would normally start this with the percentage and I don't see why you want to use rate.

Comment: I understand why you find it unnecessary. It's not just about finishing the sentence, sometimes it's me trying to solve my own problem and I don't want to explain it every time I post something because it's kinda lengthy. In some other forums, one can write a description for their account and it automatically goes with every post and comment they later write. That way, I don't have to give the reason why I ask the questions over and over again, but it seems that there's no such function here.

Answer (score 2):

*Rate* is usually a shorthand for what is more precisely described as a *time rate*. Usually, but not always. We do also have *exchange rates* between currencies, for example.

At any rate [pun sort of intended], your first sentence is poorly expressed. Is it intended to mean that (100 – *X*)% of people in Japan die before reaching age 65?

Likewise, your second sentence should be something like *The **proportion*** [or **fraction**] *of Japanese people in Japan who are age 65 or older is X%*. Or, simpler still, *Ex percent* [so, the number *X* spelled out in words] *of people in Japan are age 65 or older*. Or *In Japan, *X*% of people…*.

Comment: I find it confusing how we can talk about **poverty rate**, that is the ratio of the number of people (in a given age group) whose income falls below the poverty line, but we can't use _"the rate of"_ to refer to the ratio of the number of people (in a country) whose age is 65 or over. Could you help me work this out?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not. **Rate** means 'speed' - we all get (numerically) older at exactly the same rate! You can't use it to mean a number of people out of a population.

Comment: I think your explanation poses the same question to me as Paul's does.

Comment: By the way, if this is allowed, could you tell me if I should use "as" or "like" in my above statement?

Comment: OK, we can use _rate_ with abstract nouns like _poverty, crime_, but not with specific figures like people's age. (Yes - "The same... as..." is correct.)

Comment: It seems like your answer and Tim's are different. Do you agree with each other?

Comment: My first thought on reading your sentences was of the 'speed' sense - "The rate at which people reach the age of 65" - so that's what I referred to in my answer. But Tim is perfectly correct in saying that _rate_ is also used in expressions like _crime rate_ to refer to how much something occurs in a society. However, all of us have told you that you can't use it with reference to the number of people in a particular age group.

Answer (score 1):

The word "rate" is often used to express a volatile number (one that changes monthly, say). We speak of the "rate of unemployment", which is expressed as a percentage of the population that are able to work.  There's also the "poverty rate". People move in and out of the category "poverty" based on a variety of factors, including the then current cost-of-living. One month they might be on the borderline of poverty and the next month find themselves considered to be in that category.

But for something measured and reported on far less frequently than monthly, and which therefore doesn't have an oft-used name like "unemployment rate" or "poverty rate", "rate" is not really suitable. Your second sentence

> The rate of the 65-and-over age group in Japan is X%.

is not how a native speaker of English is likely to phrase it. Here are some possibilities but there are many variants:

> People aged 65 and over constitute  _______% of the Japanese population.
>
> ____% of the people in Japan are 65 or older.